# R package 'gtsummary' is not showing the date summary properly

Tags: r, gtsummary

The R package `gtsummary` is not showing the `date` datatype variable's summary properly. It is showing like factors even after explicitly converting the variable to `date` datatype using `as.Date` function. But at the same time it is showing properly for some other `date` datatype variables. I checked both the variables with `class` function and both of the variables are `Date` datatype. Can someone please help.

```
class(d$`UGI bleed`)
[1] "Date"
class(d$`LGI bleed`)
[1] "Date"
```

[image]

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? Please include sample data using `dput(df)` along with your question, so that we can reproduce it.

Comment: Check out the tbl_summary() help file. The section for the type argument indicates that even numeric variables wither fewer than 10 unique levels will default to a categorical summary. You can use the type argument to change this default to a continuous summary.

Comment: works like a charm..  I just added this `tbl_summary(type=list(c('LGI bleed') ~ "continuous"))`